# Java Vector of Class objects

Tags: java

I want to create a vector of custom class objects dynamically. When the program is running the tableClassName Variable contains the class name  that is rerieved from a xml request.  It's giving me a error when i tried the below way.

```
 Class tableClass = Class.forName(tableClassName).asSubclass(comm.Table.class);
 Vector<tableClass> MappingLookupResu = new Vector<tableClass>();
```

Comment: Java rule #47: Don't use `Vector` (it's a broken class)

Answer (score 2):

That's like writing `mappingLookupResult = new Vector< String.class >();`

`mappingLookupResult = new Vector< String >();` is legal, but you're providing an object (of the "Class" class), not a class definition.  If your object is a "comm.Table", then try:

```
mappingLookupResult = new Vector< comm.Table >();
```

or

```
mappingLookupResult = new Vector< ? extends comm.Table >();
```

Also - are you using `Vector` for a specific reason?  **`ArrayList`** is faster if synchronization is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Since generics are mainly a compile-time only construct, you can't instantiate the generic type parameter (in this case `T` of `Vector<T>`) based on a `String` provided at runtime.

It wouldn't make sense anyway: whoever interacts with your `Vector` won't have the information needed to deal with the vector using the concrete type anyway.  If they did, then they could just provide you the `Class<? extends Table>` directly instead of providing the class name.

However, you can ensure that your vector type parameter has an upper bound of `Table`.  What you need to do depends on how you're actually interacting with the `Vector`.  For example, if you want to put new instances of the type into it, you need to type `tableClass`:

```
 Class<? extends Table> tableClass =      
     Class.forName(tableClassName).asSubclass(Table.class);
 Vector<Table> result  = new Vector<Table>();
 result.add(tableClass.newInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. if the vector name result is added with java.lang.Object instance entries in a function. Is there a way to go through each vector object result and type cast to tableClassName reference. How can i typecast to tableClass aa= result.get(0); I want to call some getMethods in the object aa can u paste some example code.  The problem is i get the classname dynamically from a xml request.

Comment: You can't typecast (at compile time) if you don't know the type in advance.  You might be able to typecast to a common interface if that can be guaranteed, otherwise you could try accessing the methods using reflection.